# Can the game "asphalt8" be played on iOS and Android together?

Tags: applications, ios, compatibility

I have an iPhone and my friend has an Android device. When we try to play "asphalt8" on wi fi, we can't get the app to connect with each other. If he creates a room, my device doesn't show it, and vice-versa.

Can this game be played on iOS and Android together?

Comment: It all depends on the developer. Some games, like BTD5 do not allow cross platform playing, however some do, like Spaceteam. Its up to the developer if he implements cross platform gaming or not. If its not offered, there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 4):

According to ["Diana FromGameloft" on the Gameloft forums](http://mobileforum.gameloft.com/archive/index.php/t-132460.html):

> You and your friends have to play the same version of the game on the
>   same platform/device in order to see each other.

Also ["Gameloft_Ryan" posted on Windows Phone Central forums](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-games/259888-asphalt-8-multiplayer.html) to say:

> You can only play cross-platform multiplayer with W8 and WP8 users.
>   There isn't cross-platform for Android and iOS.

So unfortunately it looks like Gameloft haven't included cross-platform multi-player in Asphalt 8, so you and your friend won't be able to play against each other.